# While debugging how does an IDE identifies the code sequence. Can the entire workflow be viewed pictorially like class diagram?

Tags: debugging, plugins, ide, cpu-architecture, handshake

I can see the plugins for debugging in plugins folder in eclipse directory & I want to explore how these programs act at machine level to implement the debugging process.

what are the basic & most essential executable programs that help in debugging in any IDE.

How does any IDE creates the complete map for execution of code/program.

I want to understand how IDE changes the addressing mode in terms of normal/general mode execution & debug mode execution.

Also especially in the case of Java where execution happens at VM(Virtual machine) level, how does the handshake is created/maintained with hardware/assembler.

Comment: "addressing mode" has a meaning in computing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) which makes no sense in the context of that sentence.  A debugger doesn't rewrite the machine language code from `[rax + rdi*8]` to `[rel table]` or something (to cause a fault intentionally?)  Debuggers set software breakpoints by changing an instruction (or the first byte of an instruction) to a trap instruction like x86's [`int3`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INTn:INTO:INT3:INT1.html).  (And then writing it back to the original when the user continues.)

Comment: There is really nothing special behind debugging with source: the IDE knows where each lines of code starts. This allows it to convert between a position in the source and position in the binary (at line granularity). Advanced features like variable viewing/editing are done similarly: metadata, metadata, metadata.

Comment: Thank yo for guiding @MargaretBloom . My intention was to override the behaviour of debuggers to my situation(run-time) specific scenario. Your points have helped me very well in that!